# "404Not Found" error when testing a Rest API by Postman

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest, postman

I have a very simple Rest API written with c#:

```
namespace Test.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class NewController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public bool stringCheck(string value)
        {
            if (value.Contains("love"))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the command I use in Postman:

> http://localhost:5000/api/stringcheck?str=my love

I don't get any compiler errors, but no matter what I pass as the *value* in Postman, I always get the 404. What should I do?

Comment: that's not really how you would use Postman. I think, you are new to this API building. i dont have an answer because, this is not an error. You are just using Postman and API servers wrong. 404 simply means, the Postman cannot get what you are looking for, and the API server, is telling you, you are doing it wrong. I got a demo API server here - https://github.com/Jay-study-nildana/APIServerDotNetCoreWithAuth0 . give it a go and get to know the basics.

Comment: I think your query parameter is wrong.  You are using str when it should be value.

Comment: @TimFreese. Thanks. I corrected that error, but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is from your `[Route]` values, you can't use `[Route("api/[action]")]` above of a controller since it may cause ambiguity, you need a little change to get the result, the change is specifying the `controller` too, like below:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class NewController : ControllerBase
```

And pay attention that the queryString parameter should exactly be as same as the method parameter so in postman you should call the below URL to get the result:

> http://localhost:5000/api/new/stringcheck?value=hamed

fell free to ask questions. good luck.

Comment: Thank you. I did exactly as you said, still no change. @Hamed Moghadasi